# file_get_content em parte especifica do conteúdo do sitemap

Tags: php

Galera, alguém pode me ajudar:

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
 <?php

 $url = file_get_contents('https://www.site.com.br/sitemap.xml');
 echo $url;

 ?>
```

Preciso do seguinte:

O sitemap contém várias urls com a seguinte estrutura: www.site.com.br/numero/123/ (eu preciso pegar todos os números entre o /numero/ e o /

Os links são listados juntos

```
Ex: www.site.com.br/numero/123/www.site.com.br/numero/124/www.site.com.br/numero/125/
```

Eu preciso listar da seguinte forma:

```
123
124
125 
etc...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode usar [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) com `preg_match_all` desta forma:

```
<?php

$dados = file_get_contents('https://www.site.com.br/sitemap.xml');

if (preg_match_all('#www\.site\.com\.br/numero/([^/]+)/#', $dados, $matches)) {
    $matches = $matches[1];

    foreach ($matches as $value) {
        echo $value, '<br>', PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

O `#www\.site\.com\.br/numero/([^/]+)/#` é a regex, os pontos tem o `\` na frente para escapar, pois o ponto casa com qualquer caractere (menos quebra de linhas), o que esta dentro de parenteses `([^/]+)` vai ser capturado, no caso o `[^/]` indica que o `preg_match_all` pega qualquer caractere menos o `/`, desta forma ele vai extrair tudo que vier depois de `www.site.com.br/numero/` e antes da próxima barra.

- Um pouco sobre regex: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Exemplo no [**IDEONE**](https://ideone.com/uuVF9G)

### XML

Agora se estiver usando XML e isto:

```
www.site.com.br/numero/123/www.site.com.br/numero/124/www.site.com.br/numero/125/
```

Na verdade for a visualização do teu browser que não fez renderizou o "XML", então o `preg_match` e nem o `substr` vão funcionar, supondo que teu Xml (se for mesmo um xml) seja mais ou menos assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
   <url>
      <loc>http://www.site.com.br/numero/123/</loc>
      <lastmod>2005-01-01</lastmod>
      <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
      <priority>0.8</priority>
   </url>
   <url>
      <loc>http://www.site.com.br/numero/124/</loc>
      <lastmod>2005-01-01</lastmod>
      <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
      <priority>0.8</priority>
   </url>
   <url>
      <loc>http://www.site.com.br/numero/125/</loc>
      <lastmod>2005-01-01</lastmod>
      <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
      <priority>0.8</priority>
   </url>
   <url>
      <loc>http://www.site.com.br/numero/126/</loc>
      <lastmod>2005-01-01</lastmod>
      <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
      <priority>0.8</priority>
   </url>
</urlset>
```

Então pode usar [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) ou `simplexml_load_file` (ou `simplexml_load_string`), no caso usando *simplexml*:

```
<?php

$urlset = simplexml_load_file('sitemap.xml');

foreach($urlset as $url) {
    if (preg_match('#www\.site\.com\.br/numero/([^/]+)/#', $url->loc, $match)) {
        $numeros[] = $match[1];
    }
}

foreach ($matches as $value) {
    echo $value, '<br>', PHP_EOL;
}
```

Com o `$url->loc` foi pego o valor da tag `<loc>`, se seu XML talvez tiver um formato diferente basta trocar `->loc` pelo nome da tag que usa.

Exemplo no [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/Lj06W0)

Answer (score 0):

Isso só vai funcionar se o conteúdo de **sitemap** estiver realmente na estrutura do seu exemplo. Mas caso esteja diferente terá que adaptar o código.

```
<?php
$sitemap = file_get_contents('https://www.site.com.br/sitemap.xml');
$lista = array();
$key = 0;
while (strpos($sitemap,'/numero/') > 0) {
    $sitemap = substr($sitemap,strpos($sitemap,'/numero/')+8);
    $lista[$key] = substr($sitemap,0,strpos($sitemap,'/'));
    $key++;
}
/* Aqui você já tem o Array $lista com a seguinte estrutura:
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "123"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "124"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "125"
}
*/

//Percorrendo o Array para obter o valor de cada chave...
foreach($lista as $key => $value) {
    echo $value.'<br/>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podemos fazer uso de uma função cuja finalidade será extrair 3 caracteres após ser encontrada a posição pela qual se deve iniciar a referida extração.

```
function esquerda($str, $length) {
   return substr($str, 0, $length);
}

$url = file_get_contents('https://www.site.com.br/sitemap.xml');

while (strpos($url,'/numero/') > 0) {
    $url = substr($url,strpos($url,'/numero/')+8);
    echo esquerda($url, 3);
    echo "<br>";
}
```

DOCS:

- [Funções definidas pelo usuário](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/functions.user-defined.php)
- [while](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.while.php)
- [strpos](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strpos.php)
- [substr](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php)